# Typo3 10.4.20 doesn't show form

Tags: forms, typo3, typoscript, typo3-10.x

I have created a website with a form-element using the typo3 default form generator.

In the backend the form shows up as I want, but in the frontend typo3 shows only the HTML-Code.

I have tried adding the form, `input`, `label`, `fieldset` and `legend` tags to the constant variables `styles.content.allowTags` but that doesn't work.
It looks like it just takes the affect that line-breaks are removed.

Does anyone else have this problem?
How can I solve it?

This is my Setup:

```
lib.contentElement.templateRootPaths.10 = {$website.path}fluid/Templates/
lib.contentElement.partialRootPaths.10 = {$website.path}fluid/Partials/
lib.contentElement.layoutRootPaths.10 = {$website.path}fluid/Layouts/

tt_content.gridelements_pi1 {
  templateName.field = tx_gridelements_backend_layout
  templateName.ifEmpty = GridElement
  layoutRootPaths {
    1 = {$website.path}fluid/gridelements/Layouts/
  }
  partialRootPaths {
    1 = {$website.path}fluid/gridelements/Partials/
  }
  templateRootPaths {
    1 = {$website.path}fluid/gridelements/Templates/
  }
  dataProcessing {
    10 = GridElementsTeam\Gridelements\DataProcessing\GridChildrenProcessor
    10 {
      default {
        as = children
      }
      noflexform < .default
      noflexform {
        options {
          resolveFlexFormData = 0
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

page = PAGE
page {
 headerData.5 = COA
 headerData.5 {
  wrap =<title>|</title>
  10 = TEXT
  10 {
   field = title
   noTrimWrap = || - {$website.pagetitle}|
  }
 }
 headerData.6 = COA
 headerData.6 {
  10 = TEXT
  10.field = description
  10.stdWrap {
   wrap =<meta name="description" content="|">
   required = 1
  }
 }
 headerData.7 = COA
 headerData.7 {
  10 = TEXT
  10.field = keywords
  10.stdWrap {
   wrap =<meta name="keywords" content="|">
   required = 1
  }
 }
 headerData.10 = TEXT
 headerData.10.value (
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, viewport-fit=cover" />
   <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
 )
 typeNum = 0
 shortcutIcon = {$website.path}favicon.ico
 stdWrap.space=0
 config {
  baseURL = {$website.stammurl}
 }
 includeCSS {
  screen = {$website.path}css/style.css
  screen.media = screen
  ckefontawesome = {$website.path}fontawesome/css/all.min.css
  ckefontawesome.media = all
  ralewayfont = {$website.path}fonts/Raleway/style.css
  ralewayfont.media = all
 }
 10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
 10 {
   file = {$website.path}fluid/{$website.template}
   variables {
     CONTENT < styles.content.get
     FOOTER = CONTENT
     FOOTER {
       table = tt_content
       select {
         pidInList = {$website.footer}
         orderBy = sorting
         where = colPos=0
       }
     }
   }
 }
}
tt_content.image.dataProcessing.20.maxGalleryWidth = 2600
tt_content.image.dataProcessing.20.maxGalleryWidthInText = 2600
```

This is my Template:

```
<div class="all">
    <div class="content">
        <f:format.html parseFuncTSPath="lib.parseFunc">
            {CONTENT}
        </f:format.html>
        <div class="clearer"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="scrolltop"><span class="fa fa-chevron-up"></span></div>
    <footer>
        <f:format.html parseFuncTSPath="lib.parseFunc">
            {FOOTER}
        </f:format.html>
    </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add more details what special steps you have taken to render the form. The mentioned behavior is not expected with the default setup and without 3rd party extensions.

Comment: I only use `gridelements` as 3rd party extension, but I have also tried it with gridelents deactivated.

Comment: I have tried adding the given HTML-Code as pure HTML-Element with same result.
The HTML-Code is shown, instead of the rendered form.

Comment: How does the template look? Do you use f:format.html or f:format.raw?

Comment: I've added the template to my post. I use <f:format.html>

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your help!
TRhe solution was using `</f:format.raw>` instead of `</f:format.html>`